# Add component into Article?

Tags: joomla

I need to add a component into my Joomla articles.example(i have create a article in joomla ..in this article i needed added image gallery.. that gallery functions are in one joomla component..) how to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. First, the easiest is to get a plugin specifically designed to do this. I prefer Simple Image Gallery Pro. There is a free version as well http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/1468. With this plugin, you simply upload your images to a folder for the gallery you wish to create, then reference that folder in the article you want the gallery to appear in with `{gallery}myphotos{/gallery}`

You can also replace the Joomla article with the extension K2. It has galleries within content items built in. It uses Simple Image Gallery and is written by the same developers.

Last, you can also use a plugin that allows you to load components within an article - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/2723/details.

**EDIT**
I forgot one. Last, last some of the good image gallery components also come with modules that allow you to display galleries in a module position. You would need to have a menu item or advance module manager in order to assign the module to the correct article, but it would give you a lot of flexibility in where you place the gallery.